# Loading images from sdcard into a gridview throwing Out of memory exception?

Tags: android, image, gridview, bitmap

Well from 2 days i am struggling, please someone help me to solve this issue.

I want to load the list of all images in the external storage into my gridview.

I was able to get the list of images from the system using this method.

```
  public static ArrayList<String> getFilePaths(Activity context)
    {


        Uri u = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA};
        Cursor c = null;
        SortedSet<String> dirList = new TreeSet<String>();
        ArrayList<String> resultIAV = new ArrayList<String>();

        String[] directories = null;
        if (u != null)
        {
            c = context.managedQuery(u, projection, null, null, null);
        }

        if ((c != null) && (c.moveToFirst()))
        {
            do
            {
                String tempDir = c.getString(0);
                tempDir = tempDir.substring(0, tempDir.lastIndexOf("/"));
                try{
                    dirList.add(tempDir);
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {

                }
            }
            while (c.moveToNext());
            directories = new String[dirList.size()];
            dirList.toArray(directories);

        }

        for(int i=0;i<dirList.size();i++)
        {
            File imageDir = new File(directories[i]);
            File[] imageList = imageDir.listFiles();
            if(imageList == null)
                continue;
            for (File imagePath : imageList) {
                try {

                    if(imagePath.isDirectory())
                    {
                        imageList = imagePath.listFiles();

                    }
                    if ( imagePath.getName().contains(".jpg")|| imagePath.getName().contains(".JPG")
                            || imagePath.getName().contains(".jpeg")|| imagePath.getName().contains(".JPEG")
                            || imagePath.getName().contains(".png") || imagePath.getName().contains(".PNG")
                            || imagePath.getName().contains(".gif") || imagePath.getName().contains(".GIF")
                            || imagePath.getName().contains(".bmp") || imagePath.getName().contains(".BMP")
                            )
                    {



                        String path= imagePath.getAbsolutePath();
                        resultIAV.add(path);

                    }
                }
                //  }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        return resultIAV;


    }
```

Now the trickiest part comes, i know that i cannot load the actual images as it eats up lot of memory and ultimately get an `bitmap Outofmemory exception` hence i have the image loader with executor that executes the image loading in a separate thread and load image asyncronously here is the image loader.

```
public class AbstractImageLoader {
    private static ExecutorService executorService;
    private static AbstractImageLoader loader;
    public static int maxWidth;
    Handler handler;;
    private Map<ImageView,String> imageViews;

    static {
        AbstractImageLoader.executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    }

    public AbstractImageLoader(final Context context) {
        this.imageViews = Collections.synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());
        this.handler = new Handler();
        AbstractImageLoader.maxWidth = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels / 3;
    }

    public static AbstractImageLoader getInstance(final Context context) {
        if (AbstractImageLoader.loader == null) {
            AbstractImageLoader.loader = new AbstractImageLoader(context);
        }
        return AbstractImageLoader.loader;
    }

    private void queuePhoto(final String s, final ImageView imageView, final int n) {
        AbstractImageLoader.executorService.submit(new PhotosLoader(new PhotoToLoad(s, imageView, n)));
    }

    public void DisplayImage(final String s, final ImageView imageView) {
        this.DisplayImage(s, imageView, -1);
    }

    public void DisplayImage(final String s, final ImageView imageView, final int imageResource) {
        this.imageViews.put(imageView, s);
        final Bitmap value = MemCache.get(s);
        if (value != null) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(value);
            return;
        }
        this.queuePhoto(s, imageView, imageResource);
        if (imageResource > -1) {
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
            imageView.setImageResource(imageResource);
            return;
        }
        imageView.setImageDrawable((Drawable)null);
    }

    public void DisplayImage(final String s, final ImageView imageView, final Drawable imageDrawable) {
        this.imageViews.put(imageView, s);
        final Bitmap value = MemCache.get(s);
        if (value != null) {
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(value);
        }
        else {
            this.queuePhoto(s, imageView, -1);
            if (imageDrawable != null) {
                imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
                imageView.setImageDrawable(imageDrawable);
            }
        }
    }

    public void clearCache() {
        MemCache.clear();
    }

    public void delete(final String s) {
        MemCache.remove(s);
    }

    protected Bitmap getBitmap(final String ex) {
        final Bitmap bitmap = null;


        final File file = new File((String)ex);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            final String[] list = file.getParentFile().list(new FileUtils$Filters$6());
            Object o = bitmap;
            if (list != null) {
                if (list.length != 0) {
                    o = new File(file.getParent(), list[0]);
                    final String absolutePath = ((File)o).getAbsolutePath();
                    o = ThumbUtils.getThumbnail(absolutePath, AlbumViewLoader.maxWidth);
                    return ThumbUtils.getThumbnail((String)ex, AlbumViewLoader.maxWidth);
                }
                o = bitmap;
            }
            return (Bitmap)o;
        }
        return ThumbUtils.getThumbnail((String)ex, AlbumViewLoader.maxWidth);
    }

    boolean imageViewReused(final PhotoToLoad photoToLoad) {
        final String s = imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
        return s == null || !s.equals(photoToLoad.url);
    }

    class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable
    {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;

        public BitmapDisplayer(final Bitmap bitmap, final PhotoToLoad photoToLoad) {
            this.bitmap = bitmap;
            this.photoToLoad = photoToLoad;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (!AbstractImageLoader.this.imageViewReused(this.photoToLoad)) {
                if (this.bitmap != null) {
                    this.photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(this.bitmap);
                    this.photoToLoad.imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                    return;
                }
                if (this.photoToLoad.placeholder_stub > -1) {
                    this.photoToLoad.imageView.setImageResource(this.photoToLoad.placeholder_stub);
                    this.photoToLoad.imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private class PhotoToLoad
    {
        public ImageView imageView;
        public int placeholder_stub;
        public String url;

        public PhotoToLoad(final String url, final ImageView imageView, final int placeholder_stub) {
            this.url = url;
            this.imageView = imageView;
            this.placeholder_stub = placeholder_stub;
        }
    }

    class PhotosLoader implements Runnable
    {
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;

        PhotosLoader(final PhotoToLoad photoToLoad) {
            this.photoToLoad = photoToLoad;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
             /*   if (!imageViewReused(this.photoToLoad)) {
                    return;
                }*/
                final Bitmap bitmap = AbstractImageLoader.this.getBitmap(this.photoToLoad.url);
                if (bitmap != null) {
                    MemCache.put(this.photoToLoad.url, bitmap);
                }

                    AbstractImageLoader.this.handler.post((Runnable)new BitmapDisplayer(bitmap, this.photoToLoad));

            }
            catch (Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

here is my utility class that creates bitmap:

```
  public static Bitmap getThumbnail(final String s, int n) {
        final BitmapFactory.Options bitmapFactory$Options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bitmapFactory$Options.inSampleSize = 1;
        bitmapFactory$Options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(s, bitmapFactory$Options);
        if (bitmapFactory$Options.mCancel || bitmapFactory$Options.outWidth == -1 || bitmapFactory$Options.outHeight == -1) {
            return null;
        }
        final int outHeight = bitmapFactory$Options.outHeight;
        final int outWidth = bitmapFactory$Options.outWidth;
        final float max = Math.max(n / outWidth, n / outHeight);
        n = (int)(outWidth * max);
        final int n2 = (int)(outHeight * max);
        bitmapFactory$Options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(bitmapFactory$Options, n, n);
        bitmapFactory$Options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        bitmapFactory$Options.inDither = true;
        bitmapFactory$Options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(s, bitmapFactory$Options);
        return ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(bmp, n, n, 2);
    }
```

So here are my questions:

1.In my thumbnail utility method this calculation:

```
 final float max = Math.max(n / outWidth, n / outHeight);
            n = (int)(outWidth * max);
            final int n2 = (int)(outHeight * max);
```

n is always returned as 0. hence thumbnail is not getting loaded , so for time being i hardcoded it to 212 and thumbnail loading started

But after loading certain number of images i am still getting `out of memory exception`

here is the logcat:

```
 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 347790 byte allocation with 294944 free bytes and 288KB until OOM
05-10 09:57:19.448 22498-22683/com.geekmk.audiofx W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
05-10 09:57:19.448 22498-22683/com.geekmk.audiofx W/System.err:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
05-10 09:57:19.448 22498-22683/com.geekmk.audiofx W/System.err:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStreamInternal(BitmapFactory.java:639)
05-10 09:57:19.448 22498-22683/com.geekmk.audiofx W/System.err:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:615)
05-10 09:57:19.448 22498-22683/com.geekmk.audiofx W/System.err:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:391)
05-10 09:57:19.448 22498-22683/com.geekmk.audiofx W/System.err:     at com.geekmk.audiofx.test.ThumbUtils.getThumbnail(ThumbUtils.java:66)
05-10 09:57:19.448 22498-22683/com.geekmk.audiofx W/System.err:     at com.geekmk.audiofx.test.AbstractImageLoader.getBitmap(AbstractImageLoader.java:110)
05-10 09:57:19.448 22498-22683/com.geekmk.audiofx W/System.err:     at com.geekmk.audiofx.test.AbstractImageLoader$PhotosLoader.run(AbstractImageLoader.java:171)
05-10 09:57:19.448 22498-22683/com.geekmk.audiofx W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
05-10 09:57:19.448 22498-22683/com.geekmk.audiofx W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
05-10 09:57:19.448 22498-22683/com.geekmk.audiofx W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
05-10 09:57:19.448 22498-22683/com.geekmk.audiofx W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
05-10 09:57:19.448 22498-22683/com.geekmk.audiofx W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Please help me
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are truly nearly out of heap space. Load fewer images. Recycle the `Bitmap` objects where you can (see `inBitmap` of `BitmapFactory.Options`). Allow `Bitmap` objects to be garbage-collected when they are no longer needed and cannot be recycled.

Comment: Recyle the Bitmap objects? Can you give me a reference link or explain the how to tackle this?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inBitmap

Comment: I read that blogs and after that is what i did this, It would be great if you can help me on the changes to be done in this code or where i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

> n is always returned as 0. hence thumbnail is not getting loaded , so
>   for time being i hardcoded it to 212 and thumbnail loading started

This is because you are mixing int's and float's. Try changing this code to use floats.

```
public static Bitmap getThumbnail(final String s, float n) {
```

and

```
final float outHeight = bitmapFactory$Options.outHeight;
final float outWidth = bitmapFactory$Options.outWidth;
```

Not sure why you are using final there, I don't think that's necessary.

And using something like [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) is going to save you a bunch of code and time.

You can do something like this from your Fragment or ViewHolder

```
Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.landing_screen).into(imageView1);
Picasso.with(context).load("file:///android_asset/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView2);
Picasso.with(context).load(new File(...)).into(imageView3);
```

Comment: Picasso is not going to help me , as i have already tried and the images i am dealing with are local sd card images and are huge in number

Comment: Not sure why that wouldn't help, the code snippets I provided allow you to give Picasso file locations from your local sd card: Picasso.with(context).load(new File(...)).into(imageView3);  Picasso helps you to load them as they are required rather than all at once.

Comment: I have used picasso so my last android projects for url loading but not sure if it can help me in loading local images and i tried loading image in my adapter onBindHolder()  but as it is on my main thread it is hanging so any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I use the following method for getting a bitmap that is scaled down to not throw OOM exceptions:

```
private static Bitmap getBitmapFromUri(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull Uri uri) throws IOException {

        ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor =
                context.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
        assert parcelFileDescriptor != null;
        FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = parcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor();
        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor);
        parcelFileDescriptor.close();

        TinyDB tinyDB = new TinyDB(context);
        int maxSize = Math.min(tinyDB.getInt(AppConstants.DEVICE_WIDTH, 720), tinyDB.getInt(AppConstants.DEVICE_HEIGHT, 1080));
        int outWidth;
        int outHeight;
        int inWidth = image.getWidth();
        int inHeight = image.getHeight();
        if(inWidth > inHeight){
            outWidth = maxSize;
            outHeight = (inHeight * maxSize) / inWidth;
        } else {
            outHeight = maxSize;
            outWidth = (inWidth * maxSize) / inHeight;
        }

        return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, outWidth, outHeight, false);
    }
```

In the code, `TinyDB` is a wrapper around `SharedPreferences` and I store the screen size in pixels as soon as the app starts.